# Почему не выводится переменная php?

Tags: php, html, json

Есть часть php кода:

```
$getVar = clearVar($getVar);


if ($getVar == "pricing") { // цены
    $SALE = false;
    $endDate = "15.10.2018";    
    $array_pricing = array(
        "com.b2c.all.programs.1.month"              => array( "price" => "$2", "discount" => "$1.49" ),
        "com.b2c.all.programs.3.month"              => array( "price" => "$5", "discount" => "$3.49" ),
        "com.b2c.all.programs.6.month"              => array( "price" => "$9", "discount" => "$6.49" ),
        "com.b2c.all.programs.12.month"             => array( "price" => "$12", "discount" => "$8.49" ),
        "com.b2c.all.streams.1.month"               => array( "price" => "$2", "discount" => "$1.49" ),
        "com.b2c.all.streams.3.month"               => array( "price" => "$5", "discount" => "$3.49" ),
        "com.b2c.all.streams.6.month"               => array( "price" => "$9", "discount" => "$6.49" ),
        "com.b2c.all.streams.12.month"              => array( "price" => "$12", "discount" => "$8.49" ),
        "com.b2c.all.programs.all.streams.1.month"  => array( "price" => "$3", "discount" => "$1.99" ),
        "com.b2c.all.programs.all.streams.3.month"  => array( "price" => "$7", "discount" => "$4.99" ),
        "com.b2c.all.programs.all.streams.6.month"  => array( "price" => "$12", "discount" => "$8.49" ),
        "com.b2c.all.programs.all.streams.12.month" => array( "price" => "$20", "discount" => "$13.99" )
    );
    if ( !$SALE ) { //если акции нет, очищаем discount
        foreach ($array_pricing as &$price) {
            unset($price["discount"]);
        }
    } else {
        $array_pricing["endDate"] = $endDate;
    }
    echo json_encode( $array_pricing ); // вывод на страницу статуса
}
```

Создаю файл php отдельный, подключаю файл, вывожу переменную которую хочу, но ничего не отображается...

```
<?php
    include 'api_for_mobile.php';
    echo "$endDate";
?>
```

Если объявить, что:

```
//$getVar = clearVar($getVar);
$getVar = true;
```

То отображаются и цены, а мне нужна конкретно только одна переменная `$endDate`

Comment: ну она не глобальная

Comment: ``$array_pricing["endDate"] = $endDate;`` - в ``$array_pricing`` нет поля  ``endDate``

Comment: а можно подробней ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почитайте про видимости переменных
http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.scope.php

```
    if (statement) {
        global $var;
        $var = "init";
    }
```

Другой файл:

```
global $var;
echo $var;
```

Comment: Спасибо, почитаю!